# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tornado' on ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, tornado

When I am trying to run my application I got the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./app.py", line 32, in <module>
    from pushservices.bootstrap import init_messaging_agents
  File "/home/airnotifier/airnotifier/pushservices/bootstrap.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .apns import *
  File "/home/airnotifier/airnotifier/pushservices/apns.py", line 5, in <module>
    from util import json_encode
  File "/home/airnotifier/airnotifier/util.py", line 37, in <module>
    import tornado
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tornado'
```

I tried to run this command to install tornado

```
python3 -m pip install tornado
```

then I got the following message

```
Requirement already satisfied: tornado in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (6.0.3)
```

followed by the following error log

```
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip/_internal/utils/logging.py", line 177, in emit
    self.console.print(renderable, overflow="ignore", crop=False, style=style)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/rich/console.py", line 1752, in print
    extend(render(renderable, render_options))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/rich/console.py", line 1390, in render
    for render_output in iter_render:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip/_internal/utils/logging.py", line 134, in __rich_console__
    for line in lines:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/rich/segment.py", line 245, in split_lines
    for segment in segments:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/rich/console.py", line 1368, in render
    renderable = rich_cast(renderable)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/rich/protocol.py", line 36, in rich_cast
    renderable = cast_method()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip/_internal/self_outdated_check.py", line 130, in __rich__
    pip_cmd = get_best_invocation_for_this_pip()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip/_internal/utils/entrypoints.py", line 58, in get_best_invocation_for_this_pip
    if found_executable and os.path.samefile(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/genericpath.py", line 101, in samefile
    s2 = os.stat(f2)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/bin/pip3.8'
Call stack:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip/__main__.py", line 31, in <module>
    sys.exit(_main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 70, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 101, in main
    return self._main(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 223, in _main
    self.handle_pip_version_check(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 148, in handle_pip_version_check
    pip_self_version_check(session, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip/_internal/self_outdated_check.py", line 237, in pip_self_version_check
    logger.info("[present-rich] %s", upgrade_prompt)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 1446, in info
    self._log(INFO, msg, args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 1589, in _log
    self.handle(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 1599, in handle
    self.callHandlers(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 1661, in callHandlers
    hdlr.handle(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 954, in handle
    self.emit(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip/_internal/utils/logging.py", line 179, in emit
    self.handleError(record)
Message: '[present-rich] %s'
Arguments: (UpgradePrompt(old='22.1.2', new='22.2.2'),)
```

can anyone please tell me what should I do and what is the problem ?

Comment: Are you running your first application with `python` or with `python3`?

Comment: I am running it using this command sudo pipenv run ./app.py

Comment: And do you KNOW that `pipenv` is using the same version of Python?  What if you do `sudo python3 ./app.py`?

Comment: @TimRoberts give this error : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bson.dbref'

Comment: @TimRoberts also python3 is my default version , I run the commands in this post : https://dev.to/meetsohail/change-the-python3-default-version-in-ubuntu-1ekb and made python3 the default

Comment: Tornado requires `bson`.  Looks like you haven't installed that, but it must have loaded `tornado`.

Comment: There are often multiple installations of python3 in a single system.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible scenario that could cause this:
you execute `pip install tornado` as a user but you run the tornado project as another user.
Sorry for my terrible english, hope you can understand